# Xterm.js blocking input

Tags: javascript, typescript, xtermjs

Does Xterm.js have a function for blocking input?
Similar to python's input()?

I tried everything about xterm.js, but the document really has nothing related.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, thats no possible in the same sense as `ìnput()` would do in python, because JS is single threaded and bound to the browser page thread, stopping that execution context would mean to freeze everything up.
What you can do is using a promise like this: `await new Promise(r => term.write(your_data, r));`.

Comment: Oops, I think you are looking for the opposite - waiting for some prompt actions. Well thats possible by writing some shell task, that listens for `onData` events, but does not eval input until ENTER was pressed. But again thats only possible via callback or promises, real blocking semantics is not possible in browser mainthread.

Comment: Could you describe more specifically how I should use `await` to implement `input()`?

Comment: For the onData event, I hope I could implement the `input()` function using a blocking way such as `await`. The onData event method would be an alternative method if blocking functions don't work out.

Comment: Well you need a condition, when an awaited `input` function should resolve, thats typically on pressing the enter key. So the fundamental stub could look like this (untested): `function input(s) { term.write(s); return new Promise(r => { const data = []; const disp = term.onData(inp => {if (inp === '\x13') {disp.dispose(); r(data.join('')); return;} data.push(inp); term.write(inp); })});}`